# Stripe listen and forward multiple webhooks

Tags: stripe-payments

I have two webhooks in my Stripe account, each pointing to a different endpoint:

- first webhook: endpoint: https://example.net/webhook, secret: whsec_example1, events: checkout.session.completed
- second webhook: endpoint: https://example.org/webhook, secret: whsec_example2, events: checkout.session.completed

When I run `stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/webhook`, it only forwards the events from one of the webhooks. It displays one of the secrets, and only forwards events signed with this secret.
I would like to forward events for both webhooks, is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I think your mental model of how this works is a little off! _Events_ happen on your Stripe account, and then can be sent to multiple endpoints. That might be your .net endpoint and your .org endpoint, but it's the same event, just sent twice. If you start listening with stripe-cli, events also get sent to that in addition, and then forwarded to your `forward-to` URL. And stripe-cli signs the events it forwards with the secret it logs out, yes.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I was a little off, under the incorrect impression that the CLI used the config of a single of my webhooks, your explanation is right on point, it's all clear for me now. If you post it as an answer I can accept it in order to help the next lost soul.

Comment: I also think that currently it is not possible using one CLI instance in docker because it does not support multiple options https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/issues/500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find myself consulting this question again one year later, so let me summarize the subject based on @karllekko's helpful comment:

- Stripe emits events of various [types](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types).
- A [webhook](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) associates a selection of event types to an HTTP endpoint. It means that Stripe will POST the events of these types to the specified endpoint as they occur.
- Multiple webhooks can be defined independently, each has its own secret to sign the event
- The [CLI listen command](https://stripe.com/docs/cli/listen) defines an additional temporary webhook that associates event types in `--events` to the endpoint in `--forward-to`, it will output the signing secret in the console. Also there are pleasant features (thank you stripe developers):

  - the CLI automatically tunnels HTTP so the events can reach localhost,
  - when relaunching the command, the signing secret remains the same.